# Subquery php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have this subquery:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM curriculum WHERE ci in (SELECT curriculum FROM contactados WHERE activado = 'si' AND empresa = '".$_SESSION['emp']."' )";
  echo "Rows: ".@mysql_num_rows($sql);
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error($link));
        while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

       echo $fila['nombres']." ".$fila['apellidos']or die("error");


      }
```

But it doesn´t work and I don't know why

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: @Strawberry, we need to guess))). But really, Facundo Gutierrez, write the problem

Comment: Should you really be using a JOIN here instead of a subselect?

Comment: Should you really using  `mysql_query`?

Comment: If you have time, please state the problem that you're having and any error messages you might be getting.

Comment: Please, don't join the cargo-cult of people who put `@` before function calls for no reason. Also, **stop** using `mysql_query` before you hurt yourself.  You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise, especially user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this work for you...

```
$sql = "SELECT `a`.*, `b`.`curriculum` FROM `curriculum` AS `a` 
        LEFT JOIN `contactados` AS `b` ON `a`.`ci` = `b`.`curriculum`
        WHERE `b`.`activado` = 'si' AND `b`.`empresa` = '".$_SESSION['emp']."'";
```

Comment: This is a JOIN. 'LEFT' is redundant here - as are all the backticks

Comment: i often use this way to prevent error display if data is not found... hahaha

Comment: I don't follow. From the optimizers point of view, this is identical to JOIN. Run EXPLAIN EXTENDED on your query and then SHOW WARNINGS. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: No need, just change your query ;-)

Comment: Hi, I use that code:       
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM curriculum WHERE active = 'si' and ci IN (SELECT curriculum FROM contactados WHERE activado =  'si' AND empresa =  'gades srl')",$link)or die(mysql_error($sql));
    
         In the localhost, in SQL section, it works correctly, but when I use it in PHP it doesn't work

   while($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            
                echo $fila['nombres']." ".$fila['apellidos']or die("error");
            

          }

It prints 111